# Bloqueo de url a usuarios que solo puede ingresar un administrador

Tags: php, javascript, html

**Necesito Ayuda**

Solicito una ayuda con suma urgencia, el problema es que no se como puedo restringir una url de mi sistema para un usuario que no tiene ese privilegio.

**Foto de sistema ingresado por un administrador**

Podemos observar que la url es la siguiente y como es administrador si puede ingresar a ese modulo del sistema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Modulo:** http://localhost:81/laboratorio/mercedes/proveedor/

En esta siguiente imagen podemos observar que la url es la misma, pero ya no se trata del administrador, si no de un usuario, la lógica seria que no pudiera ingresar a dicha url.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se los agradecería mucho si compartieran algo de su conocimiento para solucionar mi problema.

Comment: Lo más sencillo, y lo que se suele usar para hacerlo, son **sesiones** de **PHP**. Al ocurrir un **Login** positivo en tu aplicación, crearías esa variable de sesión. Luego tan solo te quedaría comprobar en cada página que quieres restringir si el usuario que trata de acceder tiene o no esa variable de sesión, redirigiéndole a donde tú quieras en caso de no ser un usuario autenticado. Luego en el **Logout** destruyes la variable de **sesión** y listos.

Comment: ¿Estas utilizando algún `framework` `PHP`? Los que buscas hacer se conoce como `ACL` (_Access Control List_)